Why am I getting the error (CSRF token from the 'X-Csrftoken' HTTP header has incorrect length.)?
I'm trying to send from React a PUT request to my Django server for updating a Django model field. Here's the code


const handleStatusChange = async (projectId, newStatus) => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`/api/project/${projectId}/status`, {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken': document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ status: newStatus })
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                setProjects(prevProjects => 
                    prevProjects.map(project => 
                        project.id === projectId ? { ...project, status: newStatus } : project
                    )
                );
                setStatusDropdown(null); 
                setUpdatingProjectId(null); 
            } else {
                console.error('Failed to update project status');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error updating project status:', error);
        }
    };



The problem is that the console logs the message 'Failed to update project status' because of the server error: Forbidden (CSRF token from the 'X-Csrftoken' HTTP header has incorrect length.): /api/project/1/status
WARNING:django.security.csrf:Forbidden (CSRF token from the 'X-Csrftoken' HTTP header has incorrect length.): /api/project/1/status
[06/Dec/2024 17:37:21] "PUT /api/project/1/status HTTP/1.1" 403 2549. I have no clue of what's leading to the error. I applied the same logic to another PUT request in other page and I didn't have the issue. Can somebody explain please how I can manage the csrf token length? I'm not "manually" generating such token.
I'll share the complete console error if helps:


index.js:25 Failed to update project status
handleStatusChange  @   index.js:25
await in handleStatusChange     
onClick @   index.js:61
callCallback    @   react-dom.development.js:3942
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   react-dom.development.js:3991
invokeGuardedCallback   @   react-dom.development.js:4053
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @   react-dom.development.js:4067
executeDispatch @   react-dom.development.js:8273
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder    @   react-dom.development.js:8305
processDispatchQueue    @   react-dom.development.js:8318
dispatchEventsForPlugins    @   react-dom.development.js:8329
(anónimo)   @   react-dom.development.js:8538
batchedEventUpdates$1   @   react-dom.development.js:22426
batchedEventUpdates @   react-dom.development.js:3742
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem   @   react-dom.development.js:8537
attemptToDispatchEvent  @   react-dom.development.js:6035
dispatchEvent   @   react-dom.development.js:5954
unstable_runWithPriority    @   react.development.js:2764
runWithPriority$1   @   react-dom.development.js:11306
discreteUpdates$1   @   react-dom.development.js:22443
discreteUpdates @   react-dom.development.js:3753
dispatchDiscreteEvent   @   react-dom.development.js:5919




Did you check the devtools Network tab and look at the request?  Does it have a correct-looking csrf token header?

Now I checked and found this part of the header Cookie: csrftoken=vpnV1G6swQWsxvCaY9ZGasilEIkEwZ7e; sessionid=v04sdjpndqtx7toseikuqbwx1lmdn7ve. And after that found this X-CSRFToken: undefined.

Should I add a configuration?

X-CSRFToken: undefined - this is the problem.  I guess that [name=csrfmiddlewaretoken] doesn't exist or isn't complete when handleStatusChange runs.

I see. I tried adding a meta html element with the csrf token with the attribute name= "csrfmiddlewaretoken" content = '{{csrf_token}}' in the base template, however, the first request where nothing failed before started failing. When I put in browser console in the 2 pages, where I make a PUT request, the line document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value, I get undefined in both.

And without putting that meta element, the request in one page doesn't fail and I can see the csrf token. It's quite weird.

Meta tags in general don't have a .value property, so that's where undefined comes from.  Try .content.

I tried this syntax  but I get the undefined.

'X-CSRFToken': document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').content
